# python: detecting if my method is called with 0 or 1 args

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a suite of methods that act as getters when passed zero arguments and as setters when passed a single argument.  I have two two reasonable implementations, shown below.  Is one better than the other, or is there perhaps an even better way?

```
class Thing(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._size = 0

    def sizeA(self, *args):
        if not args:
            return self._size
        self._size = args[0]
        return self

    UNIQUE_ID = []

    def sizeB(self, arg=UNIQUE_ID):
        if arg is self.UNIQUE_ID:
            return self._size
        self._size = arg
        return self
```

A couple of comments:

`sizeA()` benchmarks faster than `sizeB()`, but doesn't give me argument count checking.  `sizeB()` works, but it depends on `UNIQUE_ID` being invariant, and I wonder if there are circumstances (e.g. pickling) that would cause it to break.

P.S.: Though I'm currently developing in python-2.7, I'm open to python-3.x specific answers as appropriate.

Comment: Why not just use properties?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Good to see your comments, as always.  I'm dabbling with fluent interfaces, e.g. `Thing().size(30).color('red')` etc..., and despite [grumblings to the contrary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3884092/558639) I think fluency is a reasonable approach for my application.

Comment: You don't do that by overloading methods (which Python doesn't support anyway), you do that by returning `self`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21785689/102937

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but wouldn't checking  `if len(args):` be the most robust?

Comment: @user949300: the `*args` argument can only ever be a tuple, and tuples are only evaluated as False in a boolean context if it has zero arguments, so there is no difference in robustness.

Comment: I'm really surprised that `sizeA` wins in performance. Since there is no static checking anyway, throwing in an `assert len(args) <= 1` would make it perfect. It might not be faster than any more, though.

Answer (score 1):

A sentinel and a defaulted arg is a good way to do it. I would use an arbitrary object though, not a list (preference, and this way someone won't go about fiddling with it).

```
class A(object):
    _DEFAULT = object()

    def __init__(self):
        self._size = 0

    def sizeC(self, arg=_DEFAULT):
        if arg is not DEFAULT:
            self._size = arg
        return self._size
```

And pickle will handle it fine (it also handles it fine with a list, change `_DEAFULT` to be `[]` and change it to `print id(y._DEFAULT)`).

```
a = A()
a.sizeC(10)

x = pickle.dumps(a)
y = pickle.loads(x)

print y._DEFAULT
print y.sizeC()
print y.sizeC(20)
print y.sizeC()
print y._DEFAULT
print a._DEFAULT
```

gives

```
andy@batman:~$ p tmp.py 
<object object at 0x7ff952223090>
10
20
20
<object object at 0x7ff952223090>
<object object at 0x7ff952223090>
```

I can't think of a situation where this would cause issue, and is an accepted pattern as far as I'm aware (I don't have any citations to hand.)

Out of curiosity, what is the difference in the benchmark between the two options?